# how to filter on list_gateways() aws boto3

Tags: boto3, aws-storage-gateway

got following code and it shows all my storage gateways. I need to get info on only 1 gateway

```
import boto3
sg = boto3.client('storagegateway', 'us-east-1')
sg.list(gateways)
print (sg.list_gateways)
```

any idea how to filter out and print only a specific gw?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to filter on the specific gateway name...

```
import boto3
sg = boto3.client('storagegateway', 'us-east-1')
response = sg.list_gateways()
for gw in response['Gateways']:
    if gw['GatewayName'] == 'YOUR_GATEWAY_NAME':
        print(gw)
```

You can filter on other response elements as well (e.g. ARN, ID, etc.) by updating the IF statement. Also, if you have more than 100 storage gateway instances, you will need to handle the Marker element to retrieve all results. For more information, see Boto3 documentation here:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/storagegateway.html#StorageGateway.Client.list_gateways